# Assigning tkinter filedialog value to a different variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I wish to save the filepath we get from `filedialog()` in a variable outside the defined function `openfile()`.

Below is the code snippet I am using:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Button

root = tk.Tk()

def openfile():
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    return path

Button(root, text = "click to open the stock file", command=openfile).pack(pady=20)

file_path = openfile() # this seems to be causing the issue
```

The problem is that the `filedialog()` is getting executed without even getting clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct about the cause of the `filedialog` getting executed. Callback functions like `openfile()` can't return values because it's `tkinter` that calls them (and it ignores whatever they return). GUI programs require a different programming paradigm than you're probably used to utilized — they're [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). This means that they (mostly) only do things as a result of processing user input. For that reason you will need to save the result of calling the `askopenfilename()` function in a global variable for use later if the value isn't going to be used immediately.

`tkinter` provides several different kinds of [variable classes](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) — `BooleanVar`, `DoubleVar`, `IntVar`, and `StringVar` — that are good for this sort of thing. In the code below, I show how to use a `StringVar` to store the path.

The next step will be adding code that does something with the value getting stored in `file_path`. One possibility would be to add another GUI element, like a `Button`, that calls another function that does something with the value.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Button

root = tk.Tk()
file_path = tk.StringVar()

def openfile():
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    file_path.set(path)  # Save value returned.

Button(root, text="click to open the stock file", command=openfile).pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is something I haven’t tried yet, but would like to ask if the file_path variable as defined by you could be used as a normal string variable in python or is it confined to be used only in the tkinter setting ?

Comment: You cannot use it as a normal string variable, but you can obtain its current string value any time you need it via `file_path.get()`.

Comment: thank you for this awesome answer... i had to dabble a bit with what i wanted and was finally able to figure a workaround based on your solution.

Comment: The only hindrance i have encountered that the value can only be accessed outside the root ... which is kinda annoying but i am glad and really appreciate what you have given me to work with.

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly do you mean by "...can only be accessed outside the root"?

Comment: if i use two different tkinter segments i cant use the value of file_path i got from the 1st segment in another unless the segments are nested. Hope it made sense.

Comment: Yes, it made sense. I think it might work if you created the variable with `tk.StringVar(master=root)`. That said, you really don't need multiple `Tk` instances since you can create new windows via `tk.Toplevel`.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what you can do:

```
def open_file():
    global path
    path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

And then you can access the path variable wherever you want in the program(after the function is ran, obviously.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, but i am afraid that I have already tried the solution you have given and it doesn’t work.